# How to set default column value in the db using django 1.7.3/postgres migrations?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

It seems like default value on columns is only on the ORM layer, and is not actually setting a default value in the DB. At the same time, the ID key for example has a default modifier in the database, which tells me it is possible to do that, but not sure how?

Example code:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

creates the following table:

```
  Column   |           Type           |                          Modifiers                          
------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('myapp_host_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying(255)   | not null
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | not null
```

Is there a way to have the migration set `default current_timestamp` in the `created_at` modifiers? If not, is there a way to pass in raw SQL migrations? I need it because the database is used by other processes (e.g. batch processes) which I don't want to have to enforce things like default values on the application layer.

Comment: Going to try to override apply method in `models.Migration` and have it run raw sql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would put your code in a [`RunSQL` operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runsql), something like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('myapp', 'previous_migration'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL("alter table myapp_host alter column created_at set default current_timestamp"),
]
```

I think this approach is cleaner than trying to override `apply()`. The API makes it easy to add the SQL for the reverse operation, and because the migration infrastructure understands the semantics of `RunSQL` it might be able to make better decisions. (For example, it knows not to squash migrations across a migration that has a `RunSQL` operation.)

Comment: +1 for RunSQL. I'd also recommend [overriding the original migration using the state_operations parameter](http://pankrat.github.io/2015/django-migrations-without-downtimes/#default-values:29c4533310fb23be2fc88d399c969fd7)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I still would like to know if there are cleaner solutions:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('myapp', 'previous_migration'),
]

operations = []

def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("alter table myapp_host alter column created_at set default current_timestamp")
    return super(Migration, self).apply(project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql)
```